# Convergence in probability given that covariance matrix goes to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sequence of random vectors $\{X_n\}$ each of dimension $2\times 1$. Suppose also that I know
$$
E(X_n)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},\\\text{var}(X_n)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{n^3}&\frac{1}{n^2}\\\frac{1}{n^2}&\frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Can I say that $X_n\to 0$ in probability? If $X_n$ was a scalar, I would know how do this using the Chebyshev's inequality but for this vector case, I don't know how to approach the problem.

Comment: Why can we not apply the "scalar" approach to each coordinate of $X_{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of random vectors 
$$
\mathbf{X}_{n}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
{(X_{n})}_{1} & \cdots & {(X_{n})}_{m}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
$$
converges in probability to a constant vector $\mathbf{a}$ if $ {(X_{n})}_{i}$ converges in probability to $a_{i}$, $\forall i \in \lbrace{1, \dots, m }\rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. (I can't upvote due to low reputation.)

Comment: :) Don't worry about it.

Comment: Ah problem solved!